# When I change my <span> to <div> text disappears

Tags: html, css

Here is my snippet:

```css
.line::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
    }

    .line:hover::before {
 visibility: visible;
 -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
 transform: scaleX(1);
    }

    .line {
 position: relative;
 left: 50%;
 margin-right: -50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    }
```

```html
    <body>
    <div class="sponge">
    <span class="line"> meow <br> </span>
    <span class="line"> meow1 <br> </span>
    <div class="line"> meow2 <br> </div>
    <div class="line"> meow3 <br> </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

When the classes are spans it works well, the text is underlined.
When the classes are divs the text isn't visible.

I thought that  and  had no functional differences, so obviously I've gone wrong somewhere. Could someone correct me and improve my understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers have touched on the cause of the problem, but might be a bit misleading as to why...

First of all, a `<span>` is an inline element whereas a `<div>` is a block element, which does mean that they are in many ways different, including reacting differently to styles like `margin` or `transform`.

However, the reason that the transform does not work is not related to the width of the element, it is due to the fact that inline elements are not actually transformable elements at all, as defined [here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-1/#terminology):

> A transformable element is an element in one of these categories:
>
> an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is
>   either a block-level or atomic inline-level element, or whose display
>   property computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group,
>   table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption [CSS21]
>
> ...

*(note that an "atomic inline-level element" does not refer to standard inline elements, but rather elements with a `display` such as `inline-block`)*

Additionally, I'd like to note that while `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` do not - as pointed out in another answer - apply to inline elements, `margin-left` and `margin-right` do.

Answer (score 0):

You have `margin-right: -50%;` and `transform: translate(-50%, 0);` rules applied to the .line class. The rules have no effect on inline elements like `span` but moves your text off screen to the right in block elements like `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `<div>` is being pushed by your `transform: translate(-50%, 0%);` and half of your div went away from your view `literally -50% left away from your view`.

`<div>'s or block elements` have 100% width by default, consider updating its width to your needs or make it `display: inline-block;`.

`<span>` is a text container that automatically adjusts its size based on text content, best for text usage.

hope that helps